# Workaround for display bug of TimeSpanUpDown when changing days

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, timespan

The [`TimeSpanUpDown`](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TimeSpanUpDown&referringTitle=Home) (Extended WPF Toolkit) seems to have a display bug when the number of days changes from 0 to >0.

Here is a simple way to reproduce it:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeSpanBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Height="100" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Bind both to the same TimeSpan property in the ViewModel -->
        <xctk:TimeSpanUpDown Value="{Binding TimeSpan}"/>
        <xctk:TimeSpanUpDown Value="{Binding TimeSpan}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Enter a time span close to but below 24h. The number of days is automatically hidden.

[image]

Then press the up-arrow on the first control to increase the time span to >24h. The control now updates its display to include the number of days. The second control receives the property changed notification and also tries to update, but ends up in a weird state:

[image]

Obviously, this is a bug and should be fixed by Xceed, but does anyone know a quick and easy fix or workaround?

Comment: @jstreet Sorry, I'm currently working on a different project. I will revisit this issue sometime in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Why not roll your own? Welcome to custom control authoring! A simple starting point without the above bug, which you can customize to your heart's content:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "UP", Type = typeof(ButtonBase))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "DOWN", Type = typeof(ButtonBase))]
public class TimeSpinner : Control
{
    static TimeSpinner()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TimeSpinner), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TimeSpinner)));
    }

    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TimeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Time.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(TimeSpinner), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero));

    public TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(IntervalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IntervalProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Interval.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IntervalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Interval", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(TimeSpinner), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.FromTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour)));

    private static readonly TimeSpan OneDay = TimeSpan.FromTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);

    void UpTime()
    {
        var newTime = Time + Interval;
        if (newTime >= OneDay)
            Time = newTime - OneDay;
        else
            Time = newTime;
    }

    void DownTime()
    {
        var newTime = Time - Interval;
        if (newTime < TimeSpan.Zero)
            Time = newTime + OneDay;
        else
            Time = newTime;
    }


    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        var upButton = GetUIPart<ButtonBase>("UP");
        if(upButton != null)
            upButton.Click += upButton_Click;
        if (_upButton != null)
            _upButton.Click -= upButton_Click;
        _upButton = upButton;

        var downButton = GetUIPart<ButtonBase>("DOWN");
        if (downButton != null)
            downButton.Click += downButton_Click;
        if (_downButton != null)
            _downButton.Click -= downButton_Click;
        _downButton = downButton;
    }

    void downButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownTime();
    }

    void upButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpTime();
    }

    private ButtonBase _upButton;
    private ButtonBase _downButton;

    T GetUIPart<T>(string name) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return (T) GetTemplateChild(name);
    }
}
```

and a sample template (which should put in a ResourceDictionary called Generic.xaml in a folder called Themes at the root of your project):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TimeSpinner}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TimeSpinner}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                            <Button x:Name="UP" Content="+"/>
                            <Button x:Name="DOWN" Content="-"/>
                        </UniformGrid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why not roll my own? Because that takes a lot of time. I am not going to reimplement all the features of the TimeSpanUpDown just because of a little bug that appears in a rare edge case. Sorry, but this is not really an answer to my question.

Comment: Well, that took all of about 10 minutes to put together - how many features could you possibly want in a spinner? I think if you look into control authoring you'll find, not only is it not black magic and that you'll learn a lot about WPF from it *and* that you can have exactly what you want, but this type of control is about the simplest thing you can do. Oh well.